# In what cases should I use runOutsideAngular if I'm already using OnPush change detection

Tags: angular

I'm already using OnPush change detection with immutable data.  I'm wondering is there further optimizations I can do with my change detection by using ngZone.runOutsideAngular?  I'm just looking for some guidelines here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are not particularly related. `OnPush` controls change detection on the level of each component, while `ngZone` "sort of" triggers change detection for the entire application.

Angular uses zones, particularly `NgZone` to get notified whenever there are no more tasks. A task scheduled in a zone will be executed in this zone. So all async tasks like `setTimeout` are executed inside `NgZone`. The `ngZone.runOutsideAngular` allows you to schedule a task outside `ngZone` which means that once it's complete Angular will not be notified and no change detection will take place.

If you have some recurring async task that gets executed many times a second (like a mousemove event) then you could probably leverage `ngZone.runOutsideAngular` to avoid triggering change detection for each event. Then you could schedule a manual change detection once a second. Other than that I can't think of how it can help you optimize the application.